# Are PostgreSQL subqueries / CTE cached?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression, query-performance

By cached I mean if there is a call to subquery for every fetched row?

Few examples

```
-- Simple query
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM accounts
) AS subquery;

-- Subquery with function
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT AVG(id_groups) FROM accounts
) AS subquery;

-- More messy queries
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id_groups, AVG(id_accounts) OVER (PARTITION BY id_groups)
  FROM accounts
) AS subquery
GROUP BY subquery.id_groups, subquery.avg;
```

And moreover

Is there a difference between

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM accounts
) AS subquery;
```

And

```
WITH everything_about_accounts AS (
    SELECT * FROM accounts
)
SELECT * FROM everything_about_accounts;
```

Comment: Would using a view instead of subquery work in the same way except that in opposite to intermediate table a view has a name? I am asking here for a normal view, not materialized view because materialized view is just a table that may be refreshed easly

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: in Postgres the CTE will not be inlined: see e.g. here https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had no idea of this, thanks for commenting.  I guess SQL Server and Postgres are very different in this regard.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it was a conscious design decision from the Postgres developers back when it was implemented. The discussion on whether or not it was a good discussion are still ongoing ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About the subqueries in the `FROM` clause:**

The subquery will *not* be executed for each row returned; that would make no sense in these cases.

In the three cases you present, PostgreSQL will even *flatten* the subquery: the optimizer realizes that the subquery is unnecessary and transforms the queries accordingly.

Use `EXPLAIN` with your queries to see that in action.

**About the CTE:**

Different from subqueries in the `FROM` clause, a CTE acts as an *optimization barrier*, that is, the optimizer does not try to flatten it or push conditions into it.

Rather, the CTE is executed and the result *materialized*, and the query executes a *CTE scan* on the materialized result.

Again, use `EXPLAIN` to see it in action.

There are efforts in the PostgreSQL community to remove the limitation (or feature, because it is a way to guide the optimizer) that CTEs are always materialized.